# Finding source data behind errors in Excel 365 unpivot operation

Tags: excel-online

I am working with Excel 365.    My main worksheet has these fields:

`Ref-field1,   ref-field2, ref-field3, ... ref-field30,    value1,    value2, value3 … value13,     total`

Ref-field1 thru 30 are text fields with various reference data.

In each row, Value1 thru Value 13 have values of either 1 or null, depending of whether the valueN category applies to that row or not.

I want to unpivot this, so that each row has

```
Ref-field1,   ref-field2, ... ref-field30,    Attribute (one of value1 thru 13), Value.
```

Excel’s default option (nulls are omitted) works nicely for this.  And I know that the number of rows to expect in the output equals the sum of all value-fields in all rows.

I have done this using the Get & Transform / Power BI functions: 
I select the columns I want unpivoted, then choose Transform > Unpivot , and then Home > Close & Load.

At this point, Excel creates a new tab in my worksheet, and shows the Queries and Connections panel.   The latter shows me that there are 16 errors – and that these are three totally blank rows.

But how I can I find out what actual rows in the main table these errors are coming from?

(I cannot share the actual spreadsheet because it’s got corporate data in it.)